# CSS Fade-In/Out Background Images Showing Blank Last Image

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to apply a CSS only changing background image to a div, but for some reason at the end of the three images specified, I get a period where the background is just the original black background color. Even more odd, if I switch the transition times to 4 seconds, one of the images doesn't show at all. Does anyone have a solution? The page can be found here (link removed)

CSS:
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0
    }

```
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.crossfade > figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.crossfade > figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('assets/img/landing/gym_1.jpg');
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  background-image: url('assets/img/landing/gym_2.jpg');
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  background-image: url('assets/img/landing/weights.jpg');
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="crossfade">
<figure></figure>
<figure></figure>
<figure></figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it's your timings.

The animation lasts for 30s and for 75% of that time, the image is `opacity: 0` with no transitions. That means that after 19.5s (25% + 12s delay for `figure:nth-child(3)`), there's nothing visible for the next 10.5s until the animation starts again for `figure:nth-child(1)`.

Changing it so all values are thirds should tidy things up (i.e. 66% of the time has `opacity: 0` and updating the delays to be `10s` or the duration to be `18s`). Alternatively, you could have 4 `figures` and change the delays to multiples of `7.5`.